# How to encounter exceptions like “element not interactable” exception in selenium test without use of ExpectedConditions which are deprecated

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm turning tests in selenium which i corrected to be ok, but sometimes the test give me ko due to different exceptions like "ElementClickInterceptedException" and "element not interactable". My question is : Is there any way to encounter this kind of problem? I have found different codes on internet that use : Thread.Sleep and ExpectedConditions but the second method use deprecated code and the first one i'm not sure is good method because it will make the test very slow and will be running in large period of time.

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpectedConditions` are indeed deprecated but there is a workaround for it that replaced them:

```
Wait.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.Id("elem-id")));
```

Basically you can add any lambda expression in the `Wait.Until` function.

Check the documentation here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_DefaultWait_1_Until__1.htm

> Repeatedly applies this instance's input value to the given function until one of the following occurs:
> the function returns neither null nor false
> the function throws an exception that is not in the list of ignored exception types
> the timeout expires

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link you shared.